# How to implement search functionality in my react js app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to implement **search functionality** in my react app.

I'm using an online backend API (commerce js), with the **filter() method** but I want a better way of doing it.

```js
const SearchPage = ({ products, onAddToCart, cart, searchedProducts }) => {
  //searchedProducts is the user searched term.

  return (
    <div className="content toolBar">
      <div />
      <Grid container justify="center" spacing={1}>
        {products
          .filter(
            (product) =>
              product.name.includes(searchedProducts) ||
              product.description.includes(searchedProducts)
          )
          .map(
            (product) =>
              product.inventory.available >= 1 && (
                <Grid item key={product.id} xs={6} sm={4} md={3} lg={2}>
                  <Product
                    product={product}
                    onAddToCart={onAddToCart}
                    cart={cart}
                  />
                </Grid>
              )
          )}
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SearchPage;
```

Comment: Consult your backend to see if it provides an API for search, so you don't have to use the filter method here.

Comment: Searching in client is faster than calling api on every search if you are getting all the result on a single api call.